# Workflow Button JS in calculated column will not fire properly in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, calculated-column

The code is below. My workflow name is 'myWorkflow'

**Question 1**
Why doesn't this WF work? It is allowed to start manually and it is a single step:
Set 'Read' to YES
End Workflow

```
="<button style=""cursor:pointer;"" onclick=""{"
&"event.preventDefault();"
&"function startWorkflow(itemID, wfName) {"
&"  function __startWorkflow() {"
&"      var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),"
&"          wfsManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx,ctx.get_web()),"
&"          wfSubs = wfsManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().enumerateSubscriptionsByList(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);"
&"      ctx.load(wfSubs);"
&"      ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {"
&"          wfsEnum = wfSubs.getEnumerator();"
&"          while (wfsEnum.moveNext()) {"
&"              var wfSub = wfsEnum.get_current();"
&"              if (wfSub.get_name() === wfName) {"
&"                      wfsManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(wfSub,itemID,new     Object());"
&"                  SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Init Workflow: '+wfName+'     on item: '+itemID, false);"
&"              }}});}"
&"  if (!SP.WorkflowServices) {"
&"      var script = document.createElement('script');"
&"      script.src = '/_layouts/15/sp.workflowservices.js';"
&"      script.onload = __startWorkflow;"
&"      document.head.appendChild(script);"
&"  } else {__startWorkflow();}"
&"}"
&"var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"    
&"startWorkflow(TR.id.split(',')[1] , 'wfRead');"
&"}"">Read</button>"
```

Comment: Q1: afaik: this starts associated workflows (but I never used it) Q2: No: this code says: Hey workflow you start! If you want a signal back you have to do that at the end of the workflow, and then this code has to wait for it. FYI: extract all this code and make it work in F12 Dev Tools first

Comment: Does the Workflow Template ID change each time the same workflow is run? Sometimes it'll work, and other times, it won't. If we forget question #2 for a second, what is wrong with my script that it won't fire and run every time? Is this script only for a List? I'm very confused.

Comment: The Workflow ID changes for every new (Published) version of the Workflow; that is why so much mumbo jumbo to get hold of the correct ID is required. If you never update the Workflow definition you can hardcode the ID

Comment: What do you mean by 'workflow definition'? In your opinion, what's the ideal Workflow type that will work every time?

Comment: Not workflow Types.. Every time you Update a Workflow (not Run!) it is re-published and gets a new id

Comment: Ahhh..ok. I see. That is a very neat trick and an even neater piece of intel. Basically, I should only create the button after I'm certain that the WF will not change, correct?

Comment: yes, you need to hardcode the workflowID then.. but sometime in the future the next admin will not have a clue why a workflow is not starting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33054/discussion-between-thejdscott-and-danny-engelman).

Comment: Danny, Hi. I don't have the reputation to talk in chat. This workflow button is driving me crazy. I haven't changed or altered the workflow, but it refuses to fire or even initialize, at times. I read the blog to create my own custom URLs, but I am only using 2013 (non-initiation form WFs). I feel like I'm missing something. I made a quick WF called "wfRead" which places a checkmark in a chkbox called 'Read'. It is literally one step, and the button does not do anything. The modal alerts do appear at the top lefthand corner, though.

Comment: You have to built it step by step then and see where it fails. Take out lines you do not need to test  Start by putting ``" console.log('executing xyz');"`` at strategic locations

Comment: Thanks for the response as always, Danny. I don't know how to do that. Can you please send me some sources/literature/documentation available online that would explain how to do this (if or when you have a moment). I'd like to learn this.

Comment: Take the code, delete all lines and built it line by line. And I think a JavaScript 101 course might help as well. I can't make it any easier...

Comment: Cool. Will do it and keep you posted. Thanks for your help.